# Progress dialog showing after adding a post

Tags: java, android

i have the following code I want to execute (adding a row to database) it while a progress dialog is showing :

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.38/hu/Addpost.php?username="+username+"&fname="+firstname+"&lname="+lastname+"&dop="+now+"&content="+post3+"&type="+post_type2+"");

                try
                {

                    nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("FirstN",firstname));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LastN",lastname));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Content",post1));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type",post_type));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Dateofp",now));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",username));
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                    if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200)
                    {
                    entity=response.getEntity();
                    if(entity !=null)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"POST SUCCESFULLY ADDED",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                    }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"ERROR RERTY OR CHECK YOUR CONNECTION",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }





                    wholepost.setText("");





                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"CONNECTION ERROR",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
```

I've tried AsyncTask and threads but nothing worked,and sometimes it worked but the progress dialog was shown after the post was added, any help please ?

Comment: You are not showing progressbar code. Better use an asynctask and do away with the strictmode. Post your asynctask class inclusive progressbar code. Show also how you call your instance of your asynctask class. Do not use Toast() in doInBackground() but in onPostExecute().

Answer (score 0):

to do this right, you need to use AyncTask as Mounzer says. To do a progressBar, you're going to have to do some uploading of the data, come back and update your progressBar, load more data, etc.

Fortunately, AsyncTask makes that easy to do.  This very simple example counts to 1000
and at each iteration publishes the results with a TextView. You could easily change that to a progressBar and put your http post code in doInBVackground()

```
protected class InitTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, String, Void> {


        // add the thread ID and count to the list
        @Override
        protected void  onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            TextView tv = new TextView(mContext);
            mThreadOutput.addView(tv);
            tv.setText(values[0]);

        }

        // do the thread work. at each iteration, set the progress to be
        // updated by the UI thread
        protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params ) {

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                String s = "Thread " + params[0] + ": " + i; 
                publishProgress( s );
            }
            return null;


        }

}
```